# RegEx to match acronyms in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a program to match advanced acronyms also like

```
eCRM
L&T
T/C
Top/Bo
e-TV
SDLC
RA/VI
Ra&Vi
RaVi
JB007
```

I tried but not solved:

```
public static boolean isAcronyms(String s){
        return s.matches("\\b([a-zA-Z]\\.){2,}(?=\\s|$)");
    //    return s.matches("[A-Z].*[A-Z]");
     //   return s.matches("\\b(?:\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}){2}\\p{Ll}*\\b");
    }
```

What I like to do is A word with minimum Two capital letters with or without any other letter(Special charaters, numbers)or numbers.

Comment: Please clarify, what conditions do you need the regex to test for?  It currently sounds like any string with at least 2 capital letters should match?

Comment: Can there just be a single special character acting as a delimiter of some sort? Is there also any limit to the lengt of these acronyms? Of-topic; a lot of those examples are not acronyms but abbreviations BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
[\p{P}\p{S}\w]*[A-Z][\p{P}\p{S}\w]*[A-Z][\p{P}\p{S}\w]*
```

Java code:

```
public static boolean isAcronym(String s) {
    return s.matches("[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\w]*[A-Z][\\p{P}\\p{S}\\w]*[A-Z][\\p{P}\\p{S}\\w]*");

}
```